# .NET Core 3.1 Required string attribute set to a blank space results in ModelState.IsValid False

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-3.1, .net-core-3.1

I am upgrading from a .NET Core 2.2 to .NET Core 3.1 API. In 2.2, I could pass a blank space to a Required string field via an API call and the ModelState.IsValid would evaluate as true. However, in 3.1, this behavior appears to have changed:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-3.1#required-attribute

> On the server, a required value is considered missing if the property
>   is null. A non-nullable field is always valid, and the [Required]
>   attribute's error message is never displayed.
>
> However, model binding for a non-nullable property may fail, resulting
>   in an error message such as The value '' is invalid. To specify a
>   custom error message for server-side validation of non-nullable types,
>   you have the following options:
>
> Whitespace in a string field is considered valid input by the jQuery
>   Validation required method. Server-side validation considers a
>   required string field invalid if only whitespace is entered.

In my case, I get an error that the field in question `email-token` is required, which means that it received a null value (in the debugger I can see it has a blank space). Microsoft's solution is to set a required attribute to nullable, but the field in question is a string, so by definition it is nullable because it is a reference type - nullable applies only to value types. This smells like a bug in .NET Core 3.1.

Currently, I can get around this by passing a single character (.) from the API side, but that seems like a crummy way to do it. Is it possible to pass a blank space or is there some other way I should handle it? Or, should I just pass an arbitrary character?

.NET Core 2.2 JSON Body

```
{ 
    "data": {
        "attributes": {
            "email-token" : "",
            "new-email-address" : "test@test.com"
        },
        "type": "change-email-addresses"
    }
}
```

.NET Core 3.1 JSON Body

```
{ 
    "data": {
        "attributes": {
            "email-token" : ".",
            "new-email-address" : "test@test.com"
        },
        "type": "change-email-addresses"
    }
}
```

Comment: Weird. I've created asp.net core 2.2 web-api project and tried to pass a whitespace for the required string property and I get a proper error, because according to the documentation the same rule applies for asp.net core 2.2 too - no whitespace for  the required string

Comment: @KirylZ Do you have any recommendations on how to handle it?

Comment: Have you considered custom Required attribute? So you could incorporate in there your own logic